# Accents, urls and Firefox

Tags: php, html, url, utf-8, urlencode

I'm having some problems and I was wondering if any of you could help me.

I have my site & DB set to utf8. I have a problem when I type in accents in the query strings section **ã** turns to **%E3**, but if i use links or forms within the page it gives **%C3%A3** in the url.

What can I do?

**EDIT:** Let me try to clarify this a bit:

I'm trying to use accented characters in my URLs (query strings) but I'm having somewhat of a hard time getting this to work across multiple browsers. Some browsers like Firefox and IE output a different percent encoded string depending on whether I'm using a form within the page or typing the accented character in the address bar. Like I said in my original question, **ã** inputed in a form turns to **%C3%A3** in the url but if I type **ã** in the address bar, the browser changes that to **%E3** in the url.

This complicates things for me because if I get **%E3**, then in php/html I get an unknown character (that is the diamond question mark, correct?)

Hopefully this helps - let me know otherwise.

Comment: I've edited my question and looked through my previously asked questions. Thanks.

Comment: It's still not clear: no browser ever outputs a URL just when you have a form on an HTML page. For something to happen, you must enter text in the form, and then the server must process the form, and then the browser might chose to present a different URL. So formulate your clarification in the form: 1. this is what I do. 2. This is what happens. 3. This is what should happen instead.

Comment: @Martin: the OP is using `method="GET"` (the default method for HTML forms, actually). Whether a different URL will be presented is fully controllable by the server. The server might choose to send a redirect, the URL will then change to the server-specified redirect URL, otherwise the URL will just be the one the request was fired to (i.e., the one as specified in form `action` attribute, along with the submitted values in a query string for the case the method was `GET`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ã inputed in a form turns to %C3%A3 in the url

Depends on the form encoding, which is usually taken from the encoding of the page that contains the form. `%C3%A9` is the correct UTF-8 URL-encoded form of `ã`.

> if I type ã in the address bar, the browser changes that to %E3 in the url.

This is browser-dependent. When you put non-ASCII characters in the a URL in location bar:

```
http://www.example.com/test.p/café?café
```

WebKit browsers encode them all as UTF-8:

```
http://www.example.com/test.p/caf%C3%A9?caf%C3%A9
```

which is IMO most correct, as per [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier). However, IE and Opera, for historical reasons, use the OS's default system encoding to encode text entered into the query string only. So on a Western European Windows installation (using code page 1252), you get:

```
http://www.example.com/test.p/caf%C3%A9?caf%E9
```

For characters that aren't available in the system encoding, IE and Opera replaces them with a `?`. Firefox will use the system encoding when all the characters in the query string, or UTF-8 otherwise.

Horrible and inconsistent, but then it's pretty rare for users to manually type out query strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - this is what I'm experiencing. I guess I should change the URL to a non accented version in case the user clicks or decides to pass a non percent encoded URL that the browser outputed. Any other alternatives? Thanks again.

Comment: I've been experimenting a bit more and this really is making my head hurt. I was thinking of stripping accents but all the methods I've tried still give me the replacement character if I type an accented character in the url. I noticed Google accepts it - do you know how can I convert/deal with it? Thanks

Comment: Clicking a URI is not a problem, it's only if the user tries to copy-paste an IRI with a non-ASCII query string you have to worry. If you want to put a pastable URI on the page it will have to be already `%`-encoded: just write `...?foo=caf%C3%A9` directly, using `rawurlencode()` on a UTF-8 string. When loaded, the browser will typically show the unescaped version in the address bar. I wouldn't worry about users manually typing characters into the URI.